# Visual Studio Environment intellisence offers duplicate tags. Are they the same?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tags, servercontrols

when editing an aspx page in visual studio the intellisence offers auto insertion of the usual asp:tags, but it also offers some tags that are not prefixed with asp: and not regular html. For instance, it offers an updatepanel tag, loginview tag and an image tag. Are these some sort of short-hand for adding asp.net web controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this and it doesn't do anything. After adding the tag visual studio's intellisence doesn't suggest any attributes and it doesn't render any sort of output to the client. Still not sure why intellisence suggest them, but they aren't server controls.